# jquery parse string

Tags: jquery, string, parsing

I have an object with the id `"4x153x9x10x173"`and I need to parse the integer `"153"` from it into a variable using jquery?

```
objects.last().attr('id') // id = 4x153x9x10x173
```

Comment: Are you sure that desired value will always be after one `x` and before the second `x`?

Comment: @gdoron server side script add this value to html. think, it must be. any suggestions on how to check value when splitting for separator exists?

Comment: I couldn't understand your comment at all... :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var desired = objects.last().attr('id').split('x')[1];
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mRq9c/)